# How to protect a device from reverse polarity and over-voltage?

Tags: circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection, reverse-polarity

I am designing a device that will include a DC power jack. There is an external wall adapter that converts the 110-230 VAC from the mains to 20 VDC. Here is the schematic:

[image]

I intend to use a standard DC power jack, such as the **694106106102** from Wurth Elektronik ([URL](https://fr.farnell.com/cliff-electronic-components/fc68148/embase-pcb-alim-dc-2-1mm-pqt-10/dp/224959)). The device will draw a maximum of 2 A from 20 VDC.

Here is my concern: I cannot prevent people from inserting an incompatible wall adapter. Thus, I need to make sure that this will not completely destroy the device. I suppose I need to prevent reverse polarity and over-voltage.

Do I need to add other protections? How are these protections generally integrated? Are there classical schematics/components that are usually used? Up to which voltage should I ensure over-voltage protection?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest reverse connect circuit is a reverse biased diode connected across the input in series with a fuse.

To protect against a sustained over voltage rather than transients you can use a crow bar circuit. This is a SCR
set up to be triggered in the event of the input voltage getting too high this again blows a fuse.

The fuse for these two schemes can be the same device. There are self healing or resetable fuses available.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f25VRS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is my least favorite technique for this, partly because it relies on the very "soft" characteristics of a fuse.  Also, D2 is way too small for a multi-amp environment.  It might blow open before the fuse does, leaving the downstream circuit exposed to a large reverse voltage.

Comment: Your right that diode is a bit small but is the default in circuit lab you need to select a diode for the expected fault current. Answer edited to address.

Comment: @AnalogKid diode-fuse protection worked well for me saved a very expensive ham radio from reverse connection to a lead acid battery with hundreds of amps of short circuit current capability.

Answer (score 0):

> *I suppose I need to prevent reverse polarity and over-voltage.*

and

> *Up to which voltage should I ensure over-voltage protection?*

A wall adapter could produce 48 volts DC. There may be ones that produce more but, to put some kind of reasonable lid on the problem I would say 48 volts. As for reverse protection, a series diode of appropriate rating might be OK else, you should consider using a P-channel MOSFET wired to protect against reversals. This is a [typical reverse protection circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552381/need-help-in-understanding-the-mosfet-reverse-polarity-protection-circuit): -

[image]

Of course you can always use a parallel diode that blows a fuse or, blows a resettable fuse.

> *Do I need to add other protections?*

You could consider using a TVS diode in case of ESD or line surges but, these are used less-often.

> *How are these protections generally integrated?*

You don't tend to find an integrated solution for both reverse and over-voltage protection although I won't rule out that some are available.

> *Are there classical schematics/components that are usually used?*

The reverse protection circuit is fairly well used. As for over-voltage, either you design to work up to the maximum or you add another regulator stage that can work up to the limit.